# How to click multiple table elements in rspec with no text or data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to run rspec tests for clicking data for a part of the website which requires a number of table elements to be clicked.  These elements represent a time element ( an hour each ) but don't have any ids.
Here is the row:

```
<tr class="ranges" data-time="5AM"></tr>
```

Here is the html equivalent of what I need to click:

```
<td data-date="04/14/15" data-time="5AM" data-disable="undefined" 
class="selectable fadein-repeat"></td>
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
find('.selectable fadein-repeat', text: "5AM").click
find(:xpath, "//tr[contains(.,'5AM')]/td/a", :date => '04/13/15').click
```

I've also tried many variations of the above code but couldn't get any of them to work.

Comment: you should add ids.  it's by far the simplest way to get capybara to do what you want.

Comment: not an option at this point ...

Answer (score 0):

To use data attributes, you need to add it to your selector. Try something along the lines of:

```
find("td[data-time='5AM']").click
```

also - you can always check if it exists before trying to click on it (then change it back when you're sure it works). eg

```
expect(page).to have_selector("td[data-time='5AM']")
```